# How to apply Columnspan in RowDataBound event dynamically?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-forms-designer, cells

I need to create a column span for 4 columns in which shown in picture.
This code wont works for me..
 How to do it? Thanks in advance !!

```
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].ColumnSpan = 4; //cells[3] == "Monday"
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = e.Row.Cells[3].ToString(); 
            e.Row.Cells[7].Text  = "Actual Hours"; //"Actual hours column"
            e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false; // "Color code column"
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "From"; //" From Time column"
            e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "To"; // "To Time column"

        }
```

[image: In this,"Monday" is one column, From,To,actual Hours are columns with row values]

Comment: Are you using `wpf`? Could you please add an image/paint with more details? What is your goal what you actually want to do?

Comment: I'm using asp.net web form sir...